# TFS Command line filter mask for nested directories

Tags: powershell, version-control, tfs

What is the TFS command line filter mask to exclude nested directories?

Consider the following example:

```
       root
  ______|_______ ____________
 |              |            |
dir1           dir2      resources
 |______________
       |        |
    resources  dir3
```

I want only to filter out root/dir1/resources folder.

Based on official [MS documentation on folder comparison filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385987.aspx) I should be able to write:

1. `"!dir1\resources\"` - Does not work. 'dir1\resources' is not filtered
2. Tried `"!root\dir1\resources\"` - Also doesn't work.
3. `"!resources\"` - This filters out 'root\resources' as well and any other folder which is named 'resources'

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385987(v=vs.120).aspx) you posted above:

If you want to exclude a subset of file or folder names, you must specify the filter for the file or folder name that you want to match first and then specify the exclusion filter.
So, you need to define the Filter to be:

*dir1\;*dir2\;*resources\;*dir3\;!resources\

Then, when you do compare on the root folder, the root\dir1\resources leaf folder will be excluded.

Comment: Hi Vicky. Thanks for your answer. Maybe you could clarify couple of things for me: 1. why root\dir1\resources folder will be excluded and not \root\resources is it because of specific order in your filter? 2. It seems like in your example you first included all dirs and then excluded one. Lets assume this would work, but what if I have hundreds of deeply nested directories?